# How to remove redundant execution paths in a concatenated linq/lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

Is this the best way to concatenate these linq/lambda statements together based on conditions? So that I don't have to join on the same thing so many times.

I'm no expert but it seems like there is some redundancy? And maybe the execution path isn't the most efficient!
ex.

```
        var products = context.Products.Select(c => c);

        if (input.DefendantId != null)
        {
            products =
                from p in products
                join pd in context.ProductDefendant
                    on p.Id equals pd.ProductId
                where pd.DefendantId == input.DefendantId
                select p;
        }

        if (input.DefendantCode != null && input.DefendantId == null)
        {
            products =
                from p in products
                join pd in context.ProductDefendant
                    on p.Id equals pd.ProductId
                join d in context.Defendants
                    on pd.DefendantId equals d.Id
                where d.DefendantCode.Any(rp => EF.Functions.Like(d.DefendantCode, "%" + input.DefendantCode + "%"))
                select p;

        }

        if (input.ProductId != null)
        {
            products = products.Where(c => c.Id == input.ProductId);
        }

        if (input.ProductName != null && input.ProductId == null)
        {
            products = products.Where(c => EF.Functions.Like(c.ProductName, "%" + input.ProductName + "%"));
        }

        var productsVM =
            from p in products
            join pd in context.ProductDefendant
                on p.Id equals pd.ProductId
            join d in context.Defendants
                on pd.DefendantId equals d.Id
            select new GetProductsReturnViewModel
            {
                Id = p.Id,
                ProductName = p.ProductName,
                DefendantCode = d.DefendantCode
            };


        switch (input.SortBy + "_" + input.OrderBy)
        {
            case "productName_DESC":
                productsVM = productsVM.OrderByDescending(c => c.ProductName);
                break;
            default:
                productsVM = productsVM.OrderBy(c => c.ProductName);
                break;
        }

        if (input.PageSize != 0)
        {
            productsVM = productsVM.Skip((input.Page - 1) * input.PageSize).Take(input.PageSize);
        }

        return productsVM;
```

Comment: the semi joins in the upper part seem like they can be moved out of the inner query. Other than that, it does look fine. If GetProductsReturnViewModel is not part of the model, you may think about caching them.

Comment: I think the problem I'm having is that when I have the condition of input.DefendantCode != null && input.DefendantId == null and that section gets used the where clause is fine, but then if the condition input.ProductName != null && input.ProductId == null is used the where clause gets overwritten. So essentially if both conditions are met I need both where clauses, and currently only one is being used. I can only look at the output window to see what sql is being run

Comment: how is that clause overridden? a where applied to a filtered IQueryable should result in a IQueryable containing both conditions (AND concatenated)

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the results of the first occurrence of each `join`, and pass the join results down.

```
var ProdsProdDef = from p in context.Products
                   join pd in context.ProductDefendant on p.Id equals pd.ProductId
                   select new { p, pd };

if (input.DefendantId != null) {
    ProdsProdDef = from ppd in ProdsProdDef
                   where ppd.pd.DefendantId == input.DefendantId
                   select ppd;
}

var ProdsProdDefDef = from ppd in ProdsProdDef
                      join d in context.Defendants on ppd.pd.DefendantId equals d.Id
                      select new { ppd.p, ppd.pd, d };

if (input.DefendantCode != null && input.DefendantId == null) {
    ProdsProdDefDef = from ppdd in ProdsProdDefDef
                      where ppdd.d.DefendantCode.Any(rp => EF.Functions.Like(ppdd.d.DefendantCode, "%" + input.DefendantCode + "%"))
                      select ppdd;
}

if (input.ProductId != null) {
    ProdsProdDefDef = ProdsProdDefDef.Where(ppdd => ppdd.p.Id == input.ProductId);
}

if (input.ProductName != null && input.ProductId == null) {
    ProdsProdDefDef = ProdsProdDefDef.Where(ppdd => EF.Functions.Like(ppdd.p.ProductName, "%" + input.ProductName + "%"));
}

var productsVM = from ppdd in ProdsProdDefDef
                 select new GetProductsReturnViewModel {
                     Id = ppdd.p.Id,
                     ProductName = ppdd.p.ProductName,
                     DefendantCode = ppdd.d.DefendantCode
                 };
```